# Trouble with appending row to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to add a row to an existing CSV file. for some reason, it won't add any rows for a blank CSV...
the weird thing is that if I run over the CSV using `w` the code runs perfectly, but if I try to append to an existing CSV using `a` the process finish with no errors but I get a blank CSV.
even weirder is that if I run with `w` then run another time with `a` it works both times...

I tried this:

```
csvfile = open(r'file path', 'a', newline='')
obj = csv.writer(csvfile)
```

now I got a for loop with some condition doesn't really matter for this case.

```
for stock_symbol in mystocks:
    obj.writerow([ddate,bmo_amc,stock_symbol,company_name])
```

```
print(ddate,bmo_amc,stock_symbol,company_name)
```

```
2019-05-23 00:00:00 Before The Open WMS Advanced Drainage Systems
2019-05-23 00:00:00 Before The Open BBY Best Buy
2019-05-23 00:00:00 Before The Open BJ BJ's Wholesale
2019-05-23 00:00:00 Before The Open BRC Brady
2019-05-23 00:00:00 Before The Open HRL Hormel Foods
```

```
obj.writerow([ddate,bmo_amc,stock_symbol,company_name])
```

`csvfile.close()`

now when I rewrite the CSV file like this
`csvfile = open(r'file path', 'w', newline='')`
it works fine but I need to append some rows and not to rewrite them...

Answer (score 0):

from the doc:

A row must be an iterable of strings or numbers for Writer objects and a dictionary mapping fieldnames to strings or numbers (by passing them through str() first) for DictWriter objects.

This worked for me:

csv file look like this:

[image]

add 'alex' with height 180 to the file

```
 with open('./example.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        newPerson = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        newPerson.writerow(['alex', 180])
```

output:

[image]

edit:

I tried to infer the data structures in your updated post, and it generated a csv file with no problem using 'a' in `open()`. When use `with open() as`, no need to put `csvfile.close()` there, it auto closes for you. and are the ddate, bmo_amc, and company_name iterators as well?

```
import csv

mystocks = ['WMS', 'BBY', 'BJ', 'BRC', 'HRL']
ddate = ['2019-05-23 00:00:00']*len(mystocks)
bmo_amc = ['Before']*len(mystocks)
company_name = ['Advanced Drainage Systems', 'Besty Buy', 'BJ\'s whole food', 'Brady', 'Hormel Foods']

with open(r'./stocks.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    obj = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')   
    for index, stock_symbol in enumerate(mystocks):
        obj.writerow([ddate[index], bmo_amc[index], stock_symbol, company_name[index]])
```

Comment: well, I am not sure how is this supposed to solve my problem.
I don't get any errors for my code and when I use 'w' to rewrite the csv it works but when I use 'a' it just gives me a blank csv.

Comment: well, I can't see the whole code block pertaining to question. I am just suggesting that you may try the syntax the doc uses ( `with open() as`), and also check the delimiter if it is matching the original file. And in the for loop, what is the value of the company name and ddate, are they defined already?

Comment: updated the answer so you could see what are the values.
I tried it with your `with open() as` gave me this error 
  
`obj.writerow([ddate,bmo_amc,stock_symbol,company_name])
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: I edited it a bit, not sure it would eventually work in your case.

Comment: didn't work still the same... says the process finish with no problem. but the csv is empty

Comment: what is the data structures of ddate, bmo_amc, company_name, are they from same source? And is the csv file locked?

Comment: the data structure is a data frame from the same source. the csv isnt locked.
I just noticed that if I run the code one time with the 'w'. then run it again with 'a' it does append the stocks... not sure why.